# appendTo objects wont take action on jquery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, appendto

I have function on input change, it works for the first input that is already there, but when jscript adds aother 
Input object with appendTo, the same function does'nt work...

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function() {
$('<input name="fails[]" type="file" />').appendTo('#input_lauki');
$('<a href="#" onclick="dzest(this);return false" class="link" name="dzest" style="font-weight:normal; display:inline;">Izdzēst</a><br/>').appendTo('#input_lauki')
$('.link').css('display','inline');

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind new elements added to the DOM as well:

```
$.on("change", "input[type=file]", function() {
    $('<input name="fails[]" type="file" />').appendTo('#input_lauki');
    $('<a href="#" onclick="dzest(this);return false" class="link" name="dzest" style="font-weight:normal; display:inline;">Izdzēst</a><br/>').appendTo('#input_lauki')
    $('.link').css('display','inline');

});
```

or [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if you're using an old version of jQuery, since it has some special handling that you should read about in the docs.

Comment: $.on needs to be applied to a selected element: the example should read `$('#input_lauki').on('change', 'input[type=file]'`

Answer (score 0):

when you defined your change event handler you had a defined amount of input file, so the new input you insert later have no handler defined for that event.

you should instead capture the event to the parent `#input_lauki`

```
$("#input_lauki").on('change', 'input[type=file]', function() {
 ...
}
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TwWEt/

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change',function(){

 //your code


});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated on newer jquery version. you should use `on()` instead